# Open two images side by side

Tags: image-processing

I have to compare lots of images (gif format) manually to each other. In order to do that I do the following steps:

1. I open one image with the ubuntu image viewer
2. I semi maximize the window to one side of the screen
3. I do the same thing with the image I want to compare it to only putting it on the other side of the screen, of course

Since I need to do this for a lot of images I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this. Maybe another program?

The images I am comparing are located in different folders but have the same name. The folders contain multiple images, so it would be great to have the opportunity to select the next image from both folders.

Do you have any ideas how I could do this?

Comment: Well, I could automate opening image viewer and placing them left and right, like `./snap-images.sh  /path/to/img1.gif /path/to/img2.gif`  It's relatively simple. What's your requirements though ? Also, can you clarify this part: `would be great to have the opportunity to select the next image from both folders.` How exactly do you want this behavior to be ?

Comment: Well, this is the tricky part I guess. If I open one image with the image viewer there is a button to show the next image in the folder. I would like that for **both** images from the different folders the next image is automatically shown if I click the button once.

Comment: Hi Ole, are the images, to be compared, similar *by definition*?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly. The pictures show the same plots (for quality assurance of experimental data) filled always with slightly different information, of course. So I think the answer is yes.

Comment: "The images I am comparing are located in different folders but have the same name" I bet it could scan ALL of them and put them all side by side under each other ;-)

Comment: Not sure I understand are the images in both folders (exactly) similarly named?

Comment: Yes, they are named exactly in the same way.

Comment: ...unless there are also other images in one or both folders, simply clicking next will do then, if both folders are sorted? Imo what a script should or could do depends on what action(s) need to be taken after comparison of tye images.

Comment: Did you found any reliable tool that can do it? I know in windows, Photoshop can do it, but still can't find anything in Linux

Answer (score 5):

You could build your script from this one:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
 zenity --info --text="Usage: $0 file1 file2"  2> /dev/null
 exit
fi

feh -g 950x800+5+30 "$1" & pid1=$!
feh -g 950x800+963+30 "$2" & pid2=$!

# using xterm as a workaround to raise zenity to the top (so that is is not behind the feh windows)
#xterm -geometry 40x3-0-0 -e zenity --title="Done?" --info --text="OK or Enter when done"; 2> /dev/null 

xterm -title "${0##*/}" -geometry 70x4+750+880 -e bash -c "read -p 'Press Enter when done'"

kill $pid1 $pid2
```

Add an outer loop that will guide you through the pairs of images that you want to compare. And of course, you can modify the geometry of the `feh` windows to match your image files and monitor resolution (this was made for a 1920x1080 monitor). And you can modify and move the control window (the xterm window).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I have added an outer loop and adjusted the window size to my screen. I am having trouble now only with zenity, because it appears always in the center of my screen and is blocking the view. Can I adjust the geometry of the notification box in some way similar to the xterm?

edit: another option would be to request user input in the current terminal but than I have the problem that the terminal is not on top anymore. Would there be another workaround to fix this?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? I am testing in LXDE (of Lubuntu), but I might be able to check in Unity of standard Ubuntu or whatever you are using (if an Ubuntu flavour). If you use some exotic desktop environment, I think you should fix the position and focus of the control window yourself. - Anyway, I selected a simple xterm, positioned below the feh windows, and it works in my desktop environment. (See the edited answer.)

Comment: I am using the standard unity. But now with your edited answer it works perfect for me. This is exactly what I wanted :) Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad it works for you :-)

Comment: If you want the zenity dialog to show above other windows, you can set ```WINDOWID``` to an empty value, eg. ```export WINDOWID=``` (you don't need the xterm workaround for it).